# Django Error: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

This is my model:

```
class Stock_Total(models.Model):
    purchases   = models.ForeignKey(Purchase,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name='purchasetotal')
    stockitem   = models.ForeignKey(Stockdata,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name='purchasestock') 
    gst_rate    = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=2,default=5)

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Stock_Total)
def update_gst_rate(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.gst_rate = instance.stockitem.gst_rate

@receiver(post_save, sender=Purchase)
def trigger_gst(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.purchasetotal.save()
```

"Purchase" and "Stockdata" are other model which I have created...I just want to save the Stock_Total model whenever the Purchase model is saved i.e. when I click on save on Purchase model the Stock_Total model will automatically be updated along with the purchase model...

Do anyone have any idea?

Comment: `instance.purchasetotal` is a one-to-many relation, it can refer to zero, one, or more items. But calling `.save()` on it has no sense, since you basically would ask the database to "update thie field in the table with the values already in the table".

Comment: Is there any other way to do this???

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to save the Stock_Total model whenever the Purchase model is saved

You don't need signals for that. See below; names have been changed to protect [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?).

```
class StockTotal(models.Model):
    purchases = models.ForeignKey(
        Purchase,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='stock_totals',
    )
    # ...


class Purchase(models.Model):
    # ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        for total in self.stock_totals.all():
            # Do whatever updates you want here
            total.save()
```

Note that the `total` values in here are going to be the database values; they'll be freshly retrieved by the `[related_name].all()` call.

It's not really clear to me what you're trying to do. If you want to edit the values on the `StockTotal` instances when associated `Purchase` objects are saved, this will work; if you just want to make sure the m2m relations are maintained, you don't need to do anything for that.

If this doesn't help, please do edit your question to clarify.